# Medir distancia usando un sensor de ultrasonidos en Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Estoy tratando de medir una distancia con el sensor de ultrasonidos y todo se ve bien, pero cuando dejo el programa de unos minutos (3-4 minutos) de trabajo, el programa detiene la medida de la distancia.

[image: Programa]

Necesito que el programa no se detiene porque lo necesito para una alarma de seguridad. El programa recoge cada segundo una distancia y lo muestra en scree. Pero si la distancia es más de 10, el programa muestra un mensaje de alerta y no muestran la distancia hasta que es menos de 10. A continuación se puede ver el código:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


# Usamos la referencia BOARD para los pines GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# Definimos los pines que vamos a usar
GPIO_TRIGGER = 11
GPIO_ECHO = 13
GPIO_LED = 15

# Configuramos los pines como entradas y salidas
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT)  # Trigger
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)      # Echo
GPIO.setup(GPIO_LED ,GPIO.OUT) #Led


# -----------------------
# Definimos algunas funciones
# -----------------------

def medida():
  # Esta funcion mide una distancia
  GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
  time.sleep(0.00001)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
  start = time.time()

  while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
    start = time.time()

  while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
    stop = time.time()

  elapsed = stop-start
  distancia = (elapsed * 34300)/2

  return distancia

def media_distancia():
  # Esta funcion recoge 3 medidas
  # y devuelve la media de las 3.
  distancia1=medida()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  distancia2=medida()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  distancia3=medida()
  distancia = distancia1 + distancia2 + distancia3
  distancia = distancia / 3
  return distancia


# -----------------------
# Programa principal
# -----------------------


print ("Medida con sensor de ultrasonidos")

# Ponemos el Trigger en falso (low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
# Ponemos el Led en falso (low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)

# Metemos el bloque principal en un Try para asi poder
# comprobar si el usuario presiona Ctrl + C
# y poder ejecutar una limpieza del GPIO, esto tambien
# evita el usuario tener que ver muchos mensajes de error
try:
  while True: # Este bucle se repite siempre

# Lo primero que hago es medir la distancia
      distancia = media_distancia()
# Compruebo si la distancia es menor que 10
# Si es menor que 10 muestro la distancia por pantalla

      if distancia < 10:
        distancia = media_distancia() # Medidos la distancia 
        print ("Distancia: %.1f" % distancia, " - " , "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c")) # Mostramos la distancia por pantalla
        GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)
        time.sleep(1) # Esperamos 1 segundo
        distancia = media_distancia()
        a = 0 # Utilizo la variable a para poder para el proceso mas adelante

# Pregunto si la variable a es igual a 1
# Si lo es no hago nada y repito el if anterior
      if a == 1:
        pass
# Pero si no es 1 le asigno el valor 0
# Para poder seguir con el IF siguiente
      else: 
        a = 0
      if distancia > 10 and a == 0: # Si la distancia es mayor que 10cms
           print ("La distancia es mayor de 10 cms. Alarma activada!!", " - ", "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c")) # Se interrumpe el bucle y se muestra un aviso
           GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, True)  
           a = 1 # Pongo la variable en 1 para parar el proceso y que no se repita 
           distancia = media_distancia() # Seguimos midiento la distancia
           while distancia < 10: # Pero si la distancia vuelve a ser menor de 10
             break # Se termina este bucle y volvemos al principio nuevamente

except KeyboardInterrupt: # Si el usuario presiona crtl + C

  # Limpiamos los pines GPIO y salimos del programa

  print ("Apagando LED")
  time.sleep(1)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)
  print ("Limpiando GPIO")
  GPIO.cleanup()
  print ("GPIO limpio")
  print ("Saliendo...")
  time.sleep(1)
```

¿Por qué el programa se detiene después de unos minutos? En realidad, sigue funcionando pero deja de emdir medidas. Pero si presiono control + c para finalizar si que me muestra la secuencia de cierre de programa.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Cuando  `distancia` es >= 10 y `a` es 1 el programa no emite medidas. Emite un mensaje cuando `distancia >= 10 and a == 1` y mira a ver si esa es la condición que ocurre durante esos minutos cuando parece que el programa se detiene.

Comment: He mirado esa condición y no es. Porque incluso cambiando la medida a 3,4 etc sigue sin funcionar. El programa de queda esperando enternamente. Creo que la cosa tiene que estar en la función medida. Gracias

Comment: Cómo está conectado el sensor? Es posible que el puerto entre en modo de ahorro de energía por configuraciones del OS?

Answer (score 0):

Tu idea es correcta pero que has complicado sin necesidad. Lo que deseas es que cada segundo se obtenga una distancia (una media de tres medidas en realidad). La lectura de la media y el `sleep` se deben hacer solo en el ciclo `while` principal, no en los condicionales. De esta forma el ciclo itera cada segundo obteniendo una media. Obtenida la media hay cuatro posibilidades:

- **Distancia menor o igual a 10 con alarma desactivada**: solamente imprimimos la distancia y la fecha.
- **Distancia menor o igual a 10 con alarma activada**: desactivamos la alarma e imprimimos la distancia y fecha.
- **Distancia mayor de 10 y alarma desactivada**: activamos la alarma (led encendida y `a` = 1) e imprimimos la alerta.
- **Distancia mayor de 10 y alarma activada**: no hacemos nada.

Para lo anterior tu código sería simplemente:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


# Usamos la referencia BOARD para los pines GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# Definimos los pines que vamos a usar
GPIO_TRIGGER = 11
GPIO_ECHO = 13
GPIO_LED = 15

# Configuramos los pines como entradas y salidas
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT)  # Trigger
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)      # Echo
GPIO.setup(GPIO_LED ,GPIO.OUT) #Led

# -----------------------
# Definimos algunas funciones
# -----------------------

def medida():
    # Esta funcion mide una distancia
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
    start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
        start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
        stop = time.time()

    elapsed = stop-start
    distancia = (elapsed * 34300)/2

    return distancia

def media_distancia():
    # Esta funcion recoge 3 medidas
    # y devuelve la media de las 3.
    distancia1=medida()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    distancia2=medida()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    distancia3=medida()
    distancia = distancia1 + distancia2 + distancia3
    distancia = distancia / 3
    return distancia

# -----------------------
# Programa principal
# -----------------------

print ("Medida con sensor de ultrasonidos")

# Ponemos el Trigger en falso (low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
# Ponemos el Led en falso (low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)

try:
    a = False #Definimos la variable de estado y le damos valor False (desactivada)
    while True:
        distancia = media_distancia()

        if distancia <= 10:
            #Si la distancia es menor de 10 siempre imprimimos
            print ("Distancia: %.1f" % distancia, " - " , "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c"))

            #Debemos comprobar si la alarma está activada, de estarlo debemos desactivarla ya que la distancia es menor de 10
            if a:
                GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)
                a = False

        elif not a:
            #Si la alarma esta desactivada y la distancia es mayor de 10 activamos la alarma
            print ("La distancia es mayor de 10 cms. Alarma activada!!", " - ", "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c")) # Se interrumpe el bucle y se muestra un aviso
            GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, True)
            a = True

        #Esperamos 1 segundo antes de tomar la nueva medida
        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Apagando LED")
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)
    print ("Limpiando GPIO")
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print ("GPIO limpio")
    print ("Saliendo...")
    time.sleep(1)
```

El `elif` solo se ejecuta si el `if` anterior no lo hace. Esto implica que solo se ejecutará si la distancia es mayor de 10.

Podemos simular el programa anterior creando un iterador con medias inventadas para emular tu código sin el sensor. En el siguiente ejemplo simulamos distintas medias con dos activaciones de la alarma y su posterior rearme:

```
import time


medias = iter((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1,2))

try:
    a = False
    while True:

        try:
            distancia = next(medias)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        if distancia <= 10:
            print ("Distancia: %.1f" % distancia, " - " , "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c"))
            if a:
                a = False
        elif not a:
            print ("La distancia es mayor de 10 cms. Alarma activada!!", " - ", "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c"))
            a = True

        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Salida:

> ```
> Distancia: 1.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:40:52 2017
> Distancia: 2.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:40:53 2017
> Distancia: 3.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:40:54 2017
> Distancia: 4.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:40:55 2017
> Distancia: 5.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:40:56 2017
> Distancia: 6.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:40:57 2017
> Distancia: 7.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:40:58 2017
> Distancia: 8.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:40:59 2017
> Distancia: 9.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:00 2017
> Distancia: 10.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:01 2017
> La distancia es mayor de 10 cms. Alarma activada!!  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:02 2017
> Distancia: 1.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:07 2017
> Distancia: 2.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:08 2017
> Distancia: 3.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:09 2017
> Distancia: 4.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:10 2017
> Distancia: 5.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:11 2017
> Distancia: 6.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:12 2017
> Distancia: 7.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:13 2017
> Distancia: 8.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:14 2017
> Distancia: 9.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:15 2017
> Distancia: 10.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:16 2017
> La distancia es mayor de 10 cms. Alarma activada!!  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:17 2017
> Distancia: 1.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:18 2017
> Distancia: 2.0  -  Fecha: Fri May  5 20:41:19 2017
> ```

Te recomiendo **usar siempre 4 espacios para identar** como recomienda PEP8 y nunca uses tabulaciones. Facilitas la lectura, edición y ejecución de tu código por otros usuarios y evitas errores de identación ocasionados por el manejo de las tabulaciones en otros editores. Cuatro espacios son siempre lo mismo en cualquier editor, una tabulación depende.

Comment: Si, el problema me viene con el sensor de ultrasonidos que se queda parado cada 2-3 minutos y no me mide ninguna distancia. Creo que el problema puede estar en la función medida. Que en alguna parte de esa función el programa se queda esperando eternamente pero no consigo solucionarlo. Lo que me comentas tu para el bucle principal es una solución más optimizada gracias por compartirla.

Comment: @SergioMuñoz la función donde tomas la medida parece ser correcta, usando la lógica que doy en mi respuesta no debería haber problemas por esta parte. El problema es que para nosotros es imposible reproducir el error al no disponer del mismo hardware. Te recomendaria que uses banderas mediante `print()` en las diferentes etapas del código, incluidos los distintos pasos en la función de medida a ver si puedes identificar en que parte exacta del código se bloquea.

Comment: Gracias a todos! Ya está solucionado, era en lls whiles que nunca terminaban he puesto un tiempo máximo de espera en cada uno de ellos para que no se quede esperando eternamente

Answer (score 0):

La descripción del problema es de [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/...](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/ultrasonic-sensor-stops-after-giving-some-reading-when-running-in-thread-on-torn) y la solución es de https://4tronix.co.uk/pizazz/standardLF.py

```
# Si el objeto está muy cerca u ocurre una reprogramación
# es posible que ya se haya recibido el eco en cuyo caso
# este bucle nunca termina a menos que le digamos que termine
# después de un tiempo.
count=time.time()
while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0 and time.time()-count<0.1:
     start = time.time()
```

...

```
# Si el objeto no es detectado algunos medidores
# no bajan la linea de eco en cuyo caso este bucle
# nunca termina a menos que le digamos que termine
# después de un tiempo.
stop = time.time()
count=time.time()
while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1 and time.time()-count<0.1:
      stop = time.time()
```